# Errors on using Vuetify components in Markdown using Nuxt Content

Tags: vue.js, markdown, nuxt.js

I'm using vuetify in my Nuxt project and it is working fine in Vue components. Here is the markdown:

```
---
title: Title
description: Description
---

# Heading

<v-row>

<v-col cols="12" md="6">

### Subheading

<img src="image.jpeg" alt="Image" width="100"/>
<p>
Text 1
</p>

<v-btn icon href="https://twitter.com/jack">
    <v-icon color="#1ca0f1">mdi-twitter</v-icon>
</v-btn>

</v-col>

<v-col cols="12" md="6">
```

I'm getting errors similar to:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the
> component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
> the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at .nuxt/content/nuxt-content.dev.vue
> <Pages/about.vue> at pages/about.vue
>
>
>
> <Layouts/contentFocused.vue> at layouts/contentFocused.vue

for all `v-row`, `v-col`, `v-icon`, `v-btn` etc.

How can I use vuetify components in markdown as documented [here](https://content.nuxtjs.org/writing/#vue-components).

Comment: Can you explain how you included vuetify in nuxt-content?